# How do I get all TextFields from a pane with foreach-loop?

Tags: java, javafx

Is it possible in JavaFx to iterate through all Textfield in a pane and set the settings for all of them at once? The below dosn't work but I imagine something like this:

```
for(TextField tf : gridpane.getChildrens){      
            txf.setEditable(false);
            txf_.setBlendMode(BlendMode.DARKEN);

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given this

```
Pane pane = new Pane();

TextField textField1 = new TextField();
TextField textField2 = new TextField();

pane.getChildren().addAll(textField1, textField2);
```

you can get the textfields like this:

```
for( Node node: pane.getChildren()) {

    if( node instanceof TextField) {
        System.out.println( node);
    }

}
```

and an alternative would be to lookup the css class:

```
Set<Node> nodes = pane.lookupAll(".text-field");
for( Node node: nodes) {
    System.out.println( node);
}
```

Comment: The second solution is what I'm looking for. Thanks!!

Comment: Be careful of the second solution, you might wish to class applyCSS to call [pane.applyCss()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#applyCss--) first to ensure that CSS processing is correctly applied to the pane and it's children before performing CSS based lookups on the pane.